# invoke actions from inside an appendTo content

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a div element which I append to body element

```
$('<div class="tooltip"></div>').appendTo('body');
```

and assign to it some html

```
$('div.tooltip').html('<a class="closeme">close me</a>');
```

I want that when user click on the close me link the append div will be removed
so I did

```
$('a.closeme').click(function(){
    $('div.tooltip').remove();
});
```

but I didnt get any response even if I try a simple

```
$('a.closeme').click(function(){
    alert('hi');
})
```

I didn't get any response.
I suspect that it is behave like this due to the fact that I use the appenTo method . I will appreciate if someone could tell me how I can invoke auction from inside an appentTo element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `on()` method to attach events to an element that's currently present, or will be present in the future:

```
$('parentElementSelector').on('click','.tooltip',
    function(){
        alert('the tooltip was clicked!');
    });
```

In your case, since you're appending to the `body` element:

```
$('body').on('click','a.closeme',
    function(){
        $(this).closest('.tooltip').remove();
    });
```

Reference:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: I'd just be concerned that using `.on()` (`.live()`'s replacement) would be a bit of a shotgun approach to the problem.

Comment: It all comes down to personal use-cases. I'd rather handle this with an `on()` call, rather than binding the event-handler in the element-creation phase; but that's just me. And my posting this answer isn't to imply that any other approach is *wrong*, it's just the way I prefer. =)

Answer (score 2):

You might build it this way (**[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/HT2mK/)**)...

```
// create your new elements
$div = $('<div class="tooltip"></div>');
$a = $('<a class="closeme">close me</a>');

// attach the event to the created element
$a.click(function() {
    alert("hi");
});

// combine them
$div.html($a);

// add them to the page
$div.appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working fine for me, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4N6z/).

Did you wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Shortest way to build it would probably be something like :

```
$('<div class="tooltip"><a class="closeme">close me</a></div>').appendTo('body').on('click', function() {$(this).remove()});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a live event to the close function , simple click function will not work try this

```
  $('.closeme').live('click',function(){
     $('div.tooltip').remove();
  });
```